# Background image as banner and the related text to it query

Tags: html, css, banner

I am here to know where I'm going wrong with the code, I am new to HTML/CSS and trying to Google but no luck.

**Issue :**

- Unable to place image and text as needed.
- Image is not replacing itself with mobile version when I'm using media query.
- Break-point is around 819px and below for mobile.

**This is my code**

```css
.main-wrapper {
  max-width: 1300px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.banner-container {
  padding: 150px 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center right !important;
  .banner-content {
    color: #3A1F17;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 819px) {
  .banner-container {
    background-image: url("https://serving.photos.photobox.com/00758490381c3770325173d6abe930e9148d8f0582ad2407e9e775d8fe03b471331704e1.jpg") !important;
  }
  .banner-content {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='main-wrapper'>
  <div class="banner-container" style="background: url('https://serving.photos.photobox.com/65771836f3f64d3b55f2ce69b7a8e93c69a822788f766366b80f47332a7b4c69dc47e4ef.jpg')">
    <div class="banner-content">
      <h1>Auto-Delivery</h1>
      <p>NEVER RUN OUT OF YOUR FAVORITE MOROCCANOIL <br>PRODUCTS AGAIN.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My final design should look like this :

**For desktop :**

[image]

**For mobile :**

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code here as well. External links can change or disappear over time and then in future the question might make no sense. You can also make a runnable StackSnippet within this question without needing an external site like JSFiddle to make a demo. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The inline style set on the div itself is overwriting the change you make inside the media query. The easiest (but maybe not cleanest) way to fix this is to add an '!important' flag to the property within the media query like so:

```
background-image: url(<url>) !important;
```

Comment: It worked. But my issue is the text which I'm using should match the output. When I reduce the screen size, the desktop image also moves along with the screen. It should become responsive, and it should adapt once it reaches the breakpoint.

Comment: Image should fit within the container too. My image is zoomed in too but it should not.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out, you had a couple of issues with your css. And I am not quite sure if the first image you want for the Desktop is possible with what you provided for the background.

```css
.main-wrapper {
  max-width: 1300px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.banner-container {
background-image: url("https://serving.photos.photobox.com/65771836f3f64d3b55f2ce69b7a8e93c69a822788f766366b80f47332a7b4c69dc47e4ef.jpg") !important;
  padding: 150px 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center right !important;
  .banner-content {
color: #3A1F17;
  }
}



 @media only screen and (max-width: 819px) {
  .banner-container {
background-image: url("https://serving.photos.photobox.com/00758490381c3770325173d6abe930e9148d8f0582ad2407e9e775d8fe03b471331704e1.jpg") !important;
  }
  .banner-content {
text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='main-wrapper'>
  <div class="banner-container">
<div class="banner-content">
  <h1>Auto-Delivery</h1>
  <p>NEVER RUN OUT OF YOUR FAVORITE MOROCCANOIL <br>PRODUCTS AGAIN.</p>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```